# How to break out of SASS nested import

Tags: sass

I have a SASS file that's loaded as follows:

router.scss

```
#rootNode {
  @import "accordion";
}
```

This means that when compiled, everything in that file is prefixed with `#rootNode` . Note the trailing space after `#rootNode` . There's a dynamically-added class `.is-special` to the `#rootNode` div:

```
<div id="rootNode" class="is-special">
    <div>
        <div class="my-selector">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nested several layers deep inside accordion.scss is the rule for `.my-selector`, and I want to use the special `&` SASS parent selector to target that selector when the `.is-special` class is on any ancestor:

```
.some-rules {
  .my-selector {
    .is-special & {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

The `.is-special &` would normally mean "apply this rule to .my-selector if any of its ancestors have the .is-special class". However, because the entire file is imported under `#rootNode`, SASS actually compiles it something like this:

```
.is-special #rootNode .my-selector {
  background-color: red;
}
```

(This is a little simplified to show the core of the problem.)

Because SASS compiles `#rootNode`  before the `.my-selector`, with no space, it doesn't match.

How can I get SASS to not inject the `#rootNode` for this one particular rule if the .scss file is imported under a selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating selectors like this is always tricky, but if the `.is-special` class is always on `#rootNode`, you have the possibility to use [`@at-root`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root) and [`selector.replace`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector#replace) on the parent selector:

```scss
.some-rules {
  .my-selector {
    @at-root #{selector.replace(&, "#rootNode", "#rootNode.is-special")} {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming there is `#rootNode` up there, this will compile as:

```scss
#rootNode.is-special .some-rules .my-selector {
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can also completely replace `#rootNode` with `.is-special`:

```scss
@at-root #{selector.replace(&, "#rootNode", ".is-special")}
```

---

If you need to do this on many places, you can create a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) so you don't have to rewrite the selector each time:

```scss
@mixin specialRoot() {
  @at-root #{selector.replace(&, "#rootNode", "#rootNode.is-special")} {
    @content;
  }
}

.some-rules {
  .my-selector {
    @include specialRoot {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `.is-special` will always be on the `#rootNode` element. However, when I tried to use the `selector.replace` approach, it throws an error: SassError: There is no module with the namespace "selector". I'm using SASS v1.55.0, and the docs for selector say it's been available v1.23. Do I have to enable/import it somewhere first?

Comment: @antun Yes you have to import it with `@use "sass:selector";`